# Proguard keep fails about excluded .jar class

Tags: android, jar, proguard

I made a simple app with external .jar library.
And going to obfuscator work with ProGuard.

But stuck with errors even had proguard rules.

I don't even know "borken class file" meaning about....

Can anyone know about this problem? Thanks. (Setting options or config attached as bottom section)

```
# Messages at Android Studio

Error processing C:\Users\administator\Desktop\artest\app\src\main\libs\arsupport.jar:ac.class: broken class file?
Error processing C:\Users\administator\Desktop\artest\app\src\main\libs\arsupport.jar:am.class: broken class file?
...
...
More similar errors...
...
...    
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Can't read [C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\artest\app\src\main\libs\arsupport.jar(;;;;;;**/*.class)] 
(Can't process class [com/arsec/Programsupport.class] (Unknown verification type [46] in stack map frame))
```

and ProGuard rules

```
# proguard-rules.pro
-keep class com.arsec.** { *; }
-keep interface com.arsec.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.arsec.**
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue in my project,some suggest to reset the value ATTR_StacjMapTable to "dummy" in ClassConstants.java .then repack the proguard.jar

But I  solve the problem is get the latest ProGuard in [http://proguard.sourceforge.net the use the latest proguard to make jar. goodlucky